# Xamarin android emulator error: App not installed

Tags: android, xamarin, virtual-machine

I am trying to install app on a Nexus 4 virtual android 5.1 on Xamarin Virtual machine. If i want to install an app, I mostly get this error: App not installed  (don't get this during some installations but 95% get this error).

I did ofcourse lots of research and testing.

- Install Android studio their VM. Same error.
- found some potential solution [here](http://mobilityarena.com/fix-application-not-installed-error-androids/)

  *Reboot the phone: In times like this, first thing to do is to reboot your                  device. Or just shut down, remove and reinsert your battery. **Done and no luck**

  *Make sure to uninstall any apps you don’t use to free up space, also uninstall previous versions of the same app currently installed on your device.
  **I download them all for the first time via APKpure.com**

  *Double check the apk files you download and be sure they were completely copied or downloaded. **App are released by companies their self and are fully downloaded**

  *Try resetting app permissions by going to Settings >Apps>All>Menu key >Reset application permissions or Reset app preferences. **Done and no luck**

  *Change app installation location to Automatic or Let system decide. **don't know how this is possible without a root**

  *Make sure your SD card is not mounted or connected to a PC or elsewhere. **no Sd card**

  *For worst case scenarios, format your SD card – copy it’s contents somewhere else for backup and format. **no Sd card**

  *The last solution would be to totally wipe your device. Either by doing a factory reset under Settings or by doing a full wipe in recovery mode. **I even reinstalled Xamarin**
- Downloaded an android 4 version, no luck.
- I found lots of post where they were talking about signing. I did not change the APK files and I never managed to install them before.
- downloaded never Nexus device with A5.1 and still same error.

Help is much appriciated.

Comment: what does your `adb logcat` say regarding the installation?

Comment: Was this on a secondary install? My experience with app not installed has been due to a partial install being left on the device. You can check settings > application manager and look through the list to see if our package name for your app is in there greyed out.

Comment: @JonDouglas where can I find that `adb logcat`?

Comment: @ClintLandry I never installed one of these apps before. I booted virtual android for the first time, I download the correct APK files and want to install them for the first time.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/android_debug_log/

Comment: @JonDouglas I don't have the `android SDK`. I only installed Xamarin and virtual box to run android virtual

Comment: If you have android studio or Xamarin.Android installed, you will have an Android SDK installed somewhere. You can then use the `adb` tooling with that device/emulator to get the logs from it.

Comment: @JonDouglas With the Xamarin directory there is a file called adb.exe. When i click it, I get see a batch file running and it also closes quite quick. Is that what you mean?

Comment: You will need to use a command line to invoke it. i.e. Change the path to the location of adb.exe and run `adb logcat`. Otherwise follow the guide above.

Comment: @JonDouglas found the file. Now I keep seeing "waiting for device" while I started my android emulator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seemed to be an compatibility issue with lots of apps. I was able to retrieve the Logcat and after looking at the logcat, that was our only conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I've always had problems with Xamarin Android Emulator.

Please use the Android Emulator (AVD) instead which contains less bugs than the Xamarin one.

[Click here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) for a guide on using the Android AVD.

And in the meanwhile, you can report the bug [here](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/newbug) to Xamarin with any relevant information such as logs and errors seen during app deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried the AVD. I get the same error there so I uninstalled it again.

Comment: @Vinc199789 Is it only happening on one specific app? If yes, then you need to post any errors

Comment: No it is happening on more then one app. Even big an famous apps